# sqlite select record one by one in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, select

I have this records in the table:

```
username, password, rights, allowance
admin, asdf, admin, 20
john, qwer, user, 10
peter, zxcv, user, 10
```

I want to select one record at a time

I used:

```
for i as integer = 1 to sqliteDataReader.FieldCount
dim ss as string = "select * from xtable where recno()=" & Ctr(i)
...
Next
```

But it doesn't get 1 record at a time.

Comment: You _are_ aware that SQL in no way guarantees the order of returned records without an `order by` clause, right?

Comment: Why do you want to read a record at a time? If you process every record this has no sense, if you need a specific record you should provide a WHERE clause.

Comment: >>Why do you want to read a record at a time? Because my application needs it.

Comment: @XenKid You should really be using a `SqliteDataReader` to iterate through all the records in a table. This will use one connection and query to the database, return a whole result set, then in your application you can go through the recordset return one row at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a way to iterate using recno is described [here](http://osdir.com/ml/db.sqlite.general/2003-10/msg00050.html).

I would, however, recommend selecting individual records from a database table by using a primary key or a unique key that you've set rather than a DBMS-specific row numbering scheme.  In your case, it would probably also be best to grab all the records you will need in one query and then iterate through that set in your application code, so you don't have to repeatedly connect and select from the database.  Perhaps using a [DataTable](http://www.java2s.com/Code/VB/Database-ADO.net/PopulateDatafromdatatable.htm) or [SqliteDataReader](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitevb/read/) might be more appropriate.

Also, I should point out that you are currently iterating through records by first only getting a count of the columns in your table.  I'm not sure if the number of rows of your table is always going to be equal to the number of columns.  That would seem odd.

Comment: I have no fieldname recno, and I could not alter the table because it has been designed.  About the DataReader, I would use it if there is no solution for this method.

Comment: I really doubt before asking, Since there is no recno in sqlite or row_number, I used the dataReader loop only.